# How to passing realmid in Disconnect URL in Quickbooks online

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We have an integration with Quickbooks online (QBO) https://www.intuit.com.au/. Now, we would like to implement "Disconnect URL". We read QBO documentation and forum but could not find a proper instruction to implement "Disconnect URL"

Our app is not in the AppStore. The user connect to QBO from our website. Our question is how to pass the qbo company realmid in the disconnect url so our app know who wants to disconnect from our app? Will the disconnect url be similar to
https://mycompanyapp.com/qbo/disconnect?realmid="realmid"

Appreciate any help/suggestion!

Comment: No way to do it at the moment.
Contact QBO support team and got the response: If the user is disconnecting from the app itself, then you have the user info. If they disconnect from apps.com or Apps tab in their QuickBooks account, then the app owner will get an email about the user who disconnected from their app. There isn't a way for your database to get automatically updated. The next time you make a call with old oauth tokens, you'll get a 401.

Answer (score 3):

By including `?realmId={realmId}` at the end of disconnect url prevents us from updating the `Disconnect URL`.

[image]

I tried the suggestion described [here](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D50f00006gyVQCCA2/how-to-get-realmid-when-user-disconnect-from-app-center-or-quickbooks-online-app-tab-i-tried-to-add-realmidrealmid-to-disconnect-url-its-not-working-since-is-special-character-and-cannot-be-saved), to supply the encoded value `?realmId=%7BrealmId%7D` which returns `%7BrealmId%7D` as a realmID.

[image]

---

But just appending `?realmId=` to  disconnect url it works.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Include `?realmId={realmId}` at the end of your disconnect url and the value will be replaced on the fly with the realmId.